# Error 91 when Internet Explorer Save prompt is shown

Tags: excel, vba, loops

My goal is to open a site, input into the forms, save a report through a button, and then loop around and continue for the next entry. I am using the Microsoft WinHTTP, HTML object library, and Internet Controls.

This works so long as I have no "Open/Save As" prompt in Internet Explorer. It successfully loops through the results and clicks the report button, then restarts. However, once the prompt appears, it causes a break in line " svalue1.Value = ws.Cells(Lastrow, 1).Value " reporting Error 91, object not found, that I can't for the life of me understand. Why would the save prompt break a VBA script?

Commented out is some of the fixes I've tried, but nothing seems to resolve this issue. Am I missing something obvious?

Thank you for taking the time to help a newbie out with this! :)

```
Enum READYSTATE
    READYSTATE_UNINITIALIZED = 0
    READYSTATE_LOADING = 1
    READYSTATE_LOADED = 2
    READYSTATE_INTERACTIVE = 3
    READYSTATE_COMPLETE = 4
End Enum
Sub Test()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1") 'set the Sheet you are using here
Dim ie As New InternetExplorerMedium
'Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium
Dim HTML As HTMLDocument
Dim i As Long
Lastrow = ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
'get the last row with a value in column A
strURL = "www.coollinkExample.com" 'set your initial URL here
ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate strURL
Do While (ie.Busy Or ie.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE)
  DoEvents
Loop
Set HTML = ie.document
'-----------------INIT-----------------
'For i = 1 To Lastrow Step 1 'loop from row 1 to Last
Do While i < Lastrow 'loop from row 1 to Last
    'Do While (ie.Busy Or ie.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE)
    'DoEvents
    'Loop BUGS WHEN SAVE PROMPT IS UP?
'-----------------BODY-----------------
            'Do your data scraping here, then below go back to your initial URL to repeat the process
            delay 5
            Set svalue1 = HTML.getElementById("userNameText")
            ie.document.getElementById("userNameText").Focus
            svalue1.Value = ws.Cells(Lastrow, 1).Value 'enter the value from current cell
            delay 2
            ie.document.getElementById("btnSearchUser").Focus
            HTML.getElementsByName("btnSearchUser").Item.Click
            delay 3
            ie.document.getElementById("rptUsers_ctl00_ddlUserOptions").Focus
            HTML.getElementsByName("rptUsers_ctl00_ddlUserOptions").Item.Click
            delay 3
            ie.document.getElementById("rptUsers_ctl00_ddlUserOptions_lnkTranscript").Focus
            HTML.getElementsByName("rptUsers_ctl00_ddlUserOptions_lnkTranscript").Item.Click
            delay 3
            ie.document.getElementById("__ta").Focus
            HTML.getElementsByName("__ta").Item.Click
            delay 2
            ie.document.getElementById("__tj").Focus
            HTML.getElementsByName("__tj").Item.Click
            delay 4
            With ie.document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnExport")
            .Focus
            .Click
            End With
            delay 5
              Application.SendKeys "%{S}"
              delay 3
'-----------------END-----------------
ie.navigate strURL
delay 5
'Exit For
'Next i
i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub

'// This function below works fine.

   Private Sub delay(seconds As Long)
    Dim endTime As Date
    endTime = DateAdd("s", seconds, Now())
    Do While Now() < endTime
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `ie.navigate strURL` at the end of the loop but are not waiting for the page to load fully.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ie As InternetExplorerMedium
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument, strURL As String
    Dim i As Long, lastrow As Long
    
    strURL = "www.coollinkExample.com" 'set your initial URL here

    Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium
    ie.Visible = True
    
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    With ws
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To lastrow
            
            ' navigate to site
            ie.navigate strURL
            Do While ie.Busy Or ie.READYSTATE <> 4 'READYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE)
                DoEvents
            Loop
            Set doc = ie.document
            delay 5
            doc.getElementById("userNameText").innerText = Trim(.Cells(i, "A"))
            delay 3
            doc.getElementById("btnSearchUser").Click
            delay 3
            doc.getElementById("rptUsers_ctl00_ddlUserOptions").Click
            delay 3
            doc.getElementById("rptUsers_ctl00_ddlUserOptions_lnkTranscript").Click
            delay 3
            doc.getElementById("__ta").Click
            delay 3
            doc.getElementById("__tj").Click
            delay 3
            doc.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnExport").Click
            delay 5
            Application.SendKeys "%(S)"
            delay 3
    
        Next i
    End With
    ie.Quit
    MsgBox "Done", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This solved it wonderfully! Thank you for your assistance :)